# The extended class doesn't seem to be inheriting some stats

Tags: java, inheritance

I have three classes, `Organism`, `Creature` and `Plant`. `Creature` and `Plant` both extend `Organism`. Now, this code worked when everything was bundled into `Organism`, so I assume the GUI class isn't at fault. Basically, what is happening is only `Creature` specific stats are being generated, whereas the `Organism` stats are being ignored, returning `0`. I cannot find anything wrong with it, so I thought you  guys could help. (Ignore the mess, I am still playing around.)

### Creature Class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;


public class Creature extends Organism
{
    private char gender;
    private int strength, speed, diet, aggression;
    private int mated, maxMated;

    public Creature()
    {
        super();
        Random rand = new Random();
        if(rand.nextInt(2) == 0)
        {
            gender = 'f';
        }
        else
        {
            gender = 'm';
        }
        mated = 0;
        setStats();
    }

    public Creature(String gen[])
    {
        super(gen);
        Random rand = new Random();
        if(rand.nextInt(2) == 0)
        {
            gender = 'f';
        }
        else
        {
            gender = 'm';
        }
        x = rand.nextInt(maxX);
        y = rand.nextInt(maxY);
        setStats();
    }

    public Creature(String gen[], int newX, int newY)
    {
        super(gen, newX, newY);
        this.gene = gen;
        Random rand = new Random();
        if(rand.nextInt(2) == 0)
        {
            gender = 'f';
        }
        else
        {
            gender = 'm';
        }
        isAlive = true;
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
        setStats();
    }

    public int getAggro()
    {
        return aggression;
    }

    public int getDiet()
    {
        return diet;
    }

    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setStats()
    {
        strength = (gene[1].charAt(0)-48) + 1 + ((gene[1].charAt(1)-48) * (gene[1].charAt(2)-48));
        speed = (strength + (gene[2].charAt(0)-48) - (gene[2].charAt(1)-48) + (gene[2].charAt(2)-48))/(size + 1);
        diet = (gene[7].charAt(0)-48) + 1 + ((gene[7].charAt(1)-48) * (gene[7].charAt(2)-48)*(3/4));
        aggression = ((strength + size)/2) / (gene[8].charAt(0)-48 + gene[8].charAt(1)-48 + gene[8].charAt(2)-48 + 1);

        maxHealth = 64 + size + (strength / 2);
        maxHunger = 100 + (size - speed - aggression);

        health = maxHealth;
        hunger = maxHunger;
    }

    public Creature breed(Creature mate)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int x = rand.nextInt(gene.length);
        int y = rand.nextInt(gene[x].length());
        String geneY[] = new String[16];
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            geneY[i] = gene[i];
        }
        geneY[x] = gene[x].substring(0,y);
        geneY[x] = geneY[x] + mate.gene[x].substring(y);
        for(i = x + 1; i < 16; i++)
        {
            geneY[i] = mate.gene[i];
        }

        char newGender;
        if(rand.nextInt(2) == 0)
        {
            newGender = 'f';
        }
        else
        {
            newGender = 'm';
        }

        hunger = hunger /2;
        mate.hunger = mate.hunger /2;
        mated = mated + 1;
        mate.mated = mate.mated + 1;

        Creature temp = new Creature(geneY,this.getX(),this.getY());
        temp.mutate();
        return temp;        
    }

    public void eat(Organism b) //A eats B
    {
        b.isAlive = false;
        this.hunger = this.hunger + b.size;
    }

    public boolean isCompatible(Creature org)
    {
        int differences = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.gene.length; i++)
        {
            if(!this.gene[i].equals(org.gene[i]))
            {
                differences = differences + 1;
            }
        }
        if(differences > 1 || this.gender == org.gender || mated == maxMated || org.mated == org.maxMated)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void moveTo(Organism org)
    {
        int vectX, vectY, moveX = 0, moveY = 0;
        double angle;

        vectX = this.x - org.x;
        vectY = this.y - org.y;

        if(vectX == 0)
        {
            moveY = this.speed;
        }
        if(vectY == 0)
        {
            moveX = this.speed;
        }
        if(vectX == 0 && vectY == 0)
        {
            moveX = 0;
            moveY = 0;
        }
        if(vectX != 0 && vectY != 0)
        {
            angle = ((Math.atan((vectY)/(vectX)))/(2*Math.PI))*360;
            if(angle < 0)
            {
                angle = angle * - 1;
            }
            moveX = (int)(Math.sin(angle)*this.speed);
            moveY = (int)(Math.cos(angle)*this.speed);
        }

        if(Math.sqrt((vectX*vectX)+(vectY*vectY)) < speed)
        {
            if(vectX > 0)
            {
                this.x = this.x - vectX;
            }
            else
            {
                this.x = this.x + vectX;
            }

            if(vectY > 0)
            {
                this.y = this.y - vectY;
            }
            else
            {
                this.y = this.y + vectY;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(vectX > 0)
            {
                this.x = this.x - moveX;
            }
            else
            {
                this.x = this.x + moveX;
            }

            if(vectY > 0)
            {
                this.y = this.y - moveY;
            }
            else
            {
                this.y = this.y + moveY;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

### Organism Class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;


public class Organism 
{
    protected String gene[] = new String[16];
    protected boolean isAlive;
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int size, sense, fertility, scent;
    protected int health, hunger, maxHealth, maxHunger;
    protected int maxX = 1000;
    protected int maxY = 1000;
    private Color color = new Color(255,0,0);

    public Organism()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            gene[i] = ""+ rand.nextInt(4) + rand.nextInt(4) + rand.nextInt(4);  
        }
        isAlive = true;
        x = rand.nextInt(maxX);
        y = rand.nextInt(maxY);
        setStats();
    }

    public Organism(String gen[])
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        this.gene = gen;
        isAlive = true;
        x = rand.nextInt(maxX);
        y = rand.nextInt(maxY);
        setStats();
    }

    public Organism(String gen[], int newX, int newY)
    {
        this.gene = gen;
        isAlive = true;
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
        setStats();
    }

    public Color getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int tempX)
    {
        this.x = tempX;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int tempY)
    {
        this.y = tempY;
    }

    public int getHunger()
    {
        return hunger;
    }

    public void setHunger(int hun)
    {
        this.hunger = hun;
    }

    public int getHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int heal)
    {
        this.health = heal;
    }

    public void setStats()
    {
        size = (gene[0].charAt(0)-48) + 1 + ((gene[0].charAt(1)-48) * (gene[0].charAt(2)-48));
        sense = (gene[5].charAt(2)-48) + 1 + ((gene[5].charAt(1)-48) * (gene[5].charAt(2)-48));
        fertility = 22 - size + (gene[6].charAt(0)-48) + 1 + ((gene[6].charAt(1)-48) * (gene[6].charAt(2)-48));
        scent = (gene[8].charAt(0)-48 + gene[8].charAt(1)-48 + gene[8].charAt(2)-48);
    }

    public int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public int getSense()
    {
        return sense;
    }

    public boolean getAlive()
    {
        return isAlive;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean live)
    {
        this.isAlive = live;
    }

    public String getInfo()
    {
        String info;
        info = "Health: " + this.health + ", Hunger: "+ this.hunger + ", Status: " + this.isAlive;
        return info;
    }

    /*public String getStats()
    {
        String info = "Size: " + this.size + ", Strength: " + this.strength +
                ", Speed: " + this.speed + ", Sight: " + this.sight +
                ", Smell: " + this.smell + ", Hearing: " + this.hearing +
                ", Fertility: " + this.fertility + ", Diet: " + this.diet +
                ", Aggression: " + this.aggression + ", Scent: " + this.scent;
        return info;            
    }*/

    public String displayGene()
    {
        String geneP = "|";
        for(int i = 0; i < gene.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < gene[i].length(); j++)
            {
                switch (gene[i].charAt(j))
                {
                    case '0': geneP = geneP + 'A';
                    break;
                    case '1': geneP = geneP + 'T';
                    break;
                    case '2': geneP = geneP + 'C';
                    break;
                    case '3': geneP = geneP + 'G';
                    break;
                }
            }           
            geneP = geneP + "|";
        }
        return geneP;
    }

    public void mutate()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int i = rand.nextInt(10000) + 1;
        int affected;
        if(i > 9999)
        {
            affected = rand.nextInt(gene.length);
            i = rand.nextInt(gene[affected].length());
            int j = rand.nextInt(4);
            gene[affected] = gene[affected].substring(0,i)+j+gene[affected].substring(i+1);     
        }
    }

    public void hungerCheck()
    {
        hunger = hunger - (size / 10 + 1);
        if(hunger <= 0)
        {
            health = health - 1;
        }
        if(hunger > (maxHunger * 3)/4)
        {
            health = health + 1;
        }
    }

    public void validate()
    {       
        if(x > maxX)
        {
            x = 100;
        }
        if(x < 0)
        {
            x = 0;
        }
        if(y > maxY)
        {
            y = 100;
        }
        if(y < 0)
        {
            y = 0;
        }

        if(hunger > maxHunger)
        {
            hunger = maxHunger;
        }
        if(hunger <= 0)
        {
            hunger = 0;
        }
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            isAlive = false;
        }
        if(health > maxHealth)
        {
            health = maxHealth;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the super method from the `Creature.setStats()` method

```
public class Creature extends Organism
    public void setStats()
    {
        super.setStats(); // Call to Organism.setStats()
        ...


    }
    ....
}
```